# Writing a dictionary with name and numpy array data to text file issue

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I'm newbie in python and I'm coding some project. I need to save some data in dictionary format {name: numpy array} (and not only one dictionary) saving it to text file and then reading it from this file too. 
I use np.savetxt for this purpose.

```
import numpy as np

from DIP import dip

name = 'name'
val = dip()          #just some function to make an array

dict = {name : val}  #create a dictionary
np.savetxt('text.txt', dict)
```

But when I run the code I have this error

```
File "D:\python3.4\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1116, in savetxt
ncol = X.shape[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

What does it mean? Or maybe I can't do something like this with np arrays? I appreciate any help and advices. Thank you

EDITED. Pickle is working really well, but is it a method that can keep all the stored data without overwriting the txt? Because when I run my program from the start (lets say next day) all the data is overwritten. I need to keep all the data in my database for future storing the samples. Thank you

Comment: I think you only save `numpy.array` not dictionary.

Comment: Read the `savetxt` documentation.  It writes a simple `csv` format - rows of fixed size columns, a 2d array as a table.

Comment: Be more specific about the format you require.  How do you intend to read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`numpy.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) you can't save the dictionary. To save dictionary you can use `pickle`.

Loading dictionary in `pickle` file.

```
In [1]: pickle_obj = open("dicts.pickle","wb")
In [2]:print dict 
{'name': matrix([[1],
        [2]])}
In [3]: pickle.dump(dict, pickle_obj)
In [4]: pickle_obj.close()
```

Reading from pickle file

```
In [5]: pickle_obj = open("dicts.pickle", "rb")
In [6]: dict = pickle.load(pickle_obj)
In [7]: pickle_obj.close()
In [8]:print dict 
{'name': matrix([[1],
        [2]])}
```

Comment: I used pickle, but instead of the name and array I only have something like that: name : qcnumpy.core.multiarray
_reconstruct
qcnumpy
ndarray
qK …qCbq‡qRq(KM@…qcnumpy
dtype
q X   f8q
K K‡qRq(KX   <q
NNNJJK tqb‰B Z  ΜX+¨.¤?χΪ[{&¦?πχlΗ?ΏσsΡ?ώgdέ«Σ?έ0­»?#Ϊϋλc™?ΗΌ82Q–?>5U¨DΈ?„x€§°?ΖoΏ*ΉΒ?]άΕN,γΧ?HK2–sΠ?ς “7¥?ώ*Ϊf²?²<“,™p?Ρ:–Sσ¦?€‰!ά*’? 9ΡίHµ?³…Γbsά?μ1·<Ν?ΐ b¬|½?G€;&Ν‘?ƒƒ¥¨?jA¬ύΏ―?X~Λ'ΝχΉ?ήθ[ΔΔ?‚9Ϊ?L£~ήαΚ?ΓP%;g?»©»H%?Έ\
¦’{?ϋ­‰Ϋ¦?,ΌΊΰ?jό„I§?rΘ–
Eβ?5l°ΎNΠ?‰Τf     I think it's a problem with numpy array again...

Comment: pickle does not save text.  You use pickle to load it as well

Comment: Oh I see. That's pretty useful, thanks for a quickly response :). Is it a way to "append" my file writing to it more than one dictionary? Making it some kind of database...?

Comment: @Eloah If this answer is useful please accept it. And if you want add more. Make it as a single one and add into it.

Comment: Is it a way to do this creating the txt and put the data to it every time i run the code without overwriting it??